# how to create an user-key from a date?

Tags: encryption

I maintain a WCF service. Since it's been decided to put a version of the service in a public server, for demo/testing purposes, it's needed to add some kind of security regarding who can access the functions. So, I thought about adding a key to each function that the client must supply in order to verify his access.

But, as the software is a licensed one (by a period of time), and it's installed locally on the customer's server when it's bought, I thought that an elegant solution could be to embed the expiration date into the key, so I don't have to put some license file or something.

I'm thinking about, giving a certain date (the expiration date) I could generate a short string (like 8 characters, letters and numbers) that appears random to the user and that he can't alter into a valid one but which I could decode and get the date that it was used to generate it.

I thought about encrypting a plain date, but the algorithms I know generate a super user-unfriendly results.

I appreciate any suggestions, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the date to a single number, such as the number of days since 4 July 2017, or some semi-random starting date.  If that is too transparent, then use some type of [format preserving encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) to encrypt the day count to the same number of digits using a standard key.